# Getting the total seconds from a time_delta column python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

i have converted a variable **col1** to `to_time_delta` but now i'd like to create a new column that gives me the total seconds of the **col1**.
How can i get it?
here's my code:
**importing data**

```
data = pd.read_csv(source + 'clustering_CB\\AAA_tableau_jan_oct_19_cardiologia.txt' ,sep='\t' , engine='python')
```

converting the **col1** to timedelta:

```
ck = pd.to_timedelta(data['col1'], unit='ns')
```

here a sample of **col1**:

```
00:10:30
```

Now i'd like to create anouther column in ck database which gives me back the total seconds of **col1**
so what i expect to find is, for example,  the conversion in seconds of `00:10:30` so : 
**630 seconds**

Comment: There's a `Datetime` accessor: [`.dt.total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrote `ck = pd.to_timedelta(data['col1'], unit='ns')` your `ck` no longer have original `col1`, as you write "to create another column" I assume you want to add new columns, then you could use below code:

After your `data = pd.read_csv(...`:

```
data['td'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['col1'], unit='ns')
data['secs'] = data['td'].dt.seconds
```

will give your something like:

```
      col1              td           secs
0   7291413234      00:00:07.291413    7
1   3245345223423   00:54:05.345223   3245
```

Tested on Jupyter notebook with:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp2=u"""col1
7291413234
3245345223423
"""
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp2),sep='\t' , engine='python')
data['td'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['col1'], unit='ns')
data['secs'] = data['td'].dt.seconds
data
```

Note:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html#pandas-series-dt-seconds

> Number of seconds (>= 0 and **less than 1 day**) for each element.

ADDED after comment:  total_seconds will return float:

```
data['secs2'] = data['td'].dt.total_seconds()
data
        col1          td            secs    secs2
0   7291413234      00:00:07.291413 7       7.291413
1   3245345223423   00:54:05.345223 3245    3245.345223
```

Comment: great! thank you Alexei

Comment: @ALollz, in pandas particularly it should return seconds up to a day per docs and it returned 3245, data posted for reproduction.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov yes seems to be the case. though `total_seconds` is safer for a general conversion to seconds since it can be more than 1 day.